# How to set attributes on an element in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a simple `Directive` as follows:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[Checker]"
})
export class Checker {

    constructor(private e: ElementRef) {

    }

    OnInit() {
        this.e.nativeElement.setAttribute("spellcheck", "true");
    }

    keyFunc(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode == 74) {
            //more functionality
        }
    }

}
```

So, whenever I add this directive selector to any tag, I set the `spellcheck` attribute to `true`.

How can I set this attribute in an Angular2 way, i.e. what is the alternative Angular way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply declare the `host` property in the `@Directive` as follows:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[Checker]",
    host: { "spellcheck":"true" }
})
```

And obviously you can remove the `setAttribute()` which you are using in the `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: It would actually need to be `"attr.spellcheck" : "true"`, and it's just the alternative syntax to `@HostBinding()`. Everything you can do with Angular decorators, `@Input()`, `@Output()`, `@ViewChild()`, `@HostListener()`, ..., can be done with `host:` as well.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I actually tried without attr, and it is working too. I am not sure which is the right way. I didn't try it with attr.spellcheck though.

Comment: If you bind to a components input or DOM elements property, then `attr.` is not required, otherwise `attr.` is required.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer got it :)

Comment: Actually you were right. What I said is true for bindings in view like `[attr.spellcheck]="true"` and in `@HostBinding('attr.spellcheck') sp = true;`, but in `host: {"spellcheck":"true"}` `attr.` is not required. https://plnkr.co/edit/RyCb9Cs4g5J6fociXfKl?p=preview

Comment: Neat :) @GünterZöchbauer Could you please join my chatroom which I created!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135932/discussion-between-gunter-zochbauer-and-shellzero).

Answer (score 14):

The 'Angular 2' way would be to use [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer#setElementProperty).

`this.renderer.setElementAttribute(e.nativeElement, "spellcheck", "true");`

**Edit:**

As PeterS notes in the comments below, `renderer` has been deprecated in favour of `renderer2`, so the new command would be:

`this.renderer2.setAttribute(e.nativeElement, "spellcheck", "true")`

Comment: Can I do it using @HostBinding() by any chance?

Comment: Yet to try this, but the link was broken so: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer#setElementProperty

Comment: Thanks, @theSiberman. I updated the answer to use your new link.

Comment: Adam: Is there a way to set an @Input property to the host using renderer2 ? set [(color)] property to the Host element.

Comment: Note in angular 5 it is now setAttribute using renderer 2: this.renderer2.setAttribute(element, 'name', data)

Answer (score 12):

You an use `@HostBinding` like

```ts
export class Checker {

  @HostBinding('attr.spellcheck')
  spellcheck:boolean = true;
```