# Setting disabled to angular material components using directive

Tags: javascript, angular

As the title says I am trying to set disabled to material component using a directive. I've tried various ways, using ElementRef, Renderer, Renderer2 and querySelector. Nothing seems to be working.

Here it my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PermissionType } from './permission-type.enum';
import { Resource } from './resource.enum';
import { PermissionManagerService } from './permission-manager.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appIsGranted]'
})
export class IsGrantedDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private permissionManagerS: PermissionManagerService,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) { }

  @Input() set appIsGranted(permission: Array<string>) {
    this.isGranted(
      permission[0] as Resource,
      permission[1] as PermissionType
    )
  }

  private isGranted(resource: Resource, permissionType: PermissionType) {
    if(this.permissionManagerS.isGranted(resource, permissionType)) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      let view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      let rootElem = view.rootNodes[0];
      //this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
      //this.el.nativeElement.disabled = 'disabled';
      //this._renderer.setProperty(rootElem, 'disabled', true);

      this._renderer.setProperty(rootElem, 'disabled', 'disabled');

//      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

}
```

For example this button icon is what I am trying to disable.

```
<button mat-icon-button class="action--icon" matTooltip="Notes" matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="openNotesDialog(element.earningsFileId)" *appIsGranted="['EARNINGS', 'viewearnings']">
  <mat-icon>chat</mat-icon>
</button>
```

The idea would be that this would work across all material items by just adding the attribute `disabled` to all material components.

Comment: Instead of adding directive for disabled why not use property binding for that element like this [disabled]="yourCondition()" ?

Comment: @Indrajeet - If you use a directive you can apply it to a any element. See https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives. It's a good way to provide reusable custom behavior for DOM elements.

Comment: yes but usually disabled is available to every element right

Comment: As long as you are creating directive for disabled, that can be avoided. if the use case is different for example adding asterisk to make it look like required, it makes a lot of sense to use directive. don't you think?

Comment: @Indrajeet disabled attribute is not avilable for all elements. check this:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp

Comment: Agree, what element do you want to disable? can you give any example?

Comment: @Indrajeet This would be applied for any material component but I guess in this case we can start with the button Icon I am currently trying to disable. I added an example in the post.

Comment: @DaggeJ example html added.

Comment: @Suzed - added full directive with example usage. Have no idea why someone down-voted. This is a working example of what you are asking for. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

We are doing something similar in our app through a directive that gets passed a list of roles required for running the actions associated with the element it is set on.

It works by using JQuery's method `attr` to set `disabled` and other attributes.

**The directive**;

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appEditEntityActions]'
})
export class EditEntityActionsDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() requiresAnyRole: string[] = null;

    constructor(
        private authorizationService: AuthorizationService,
        private element: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        var userCanEdit = this.authorizationService.hasAnyClaim(this.requiresAnyRole);
        if (!userCanEdit) {
            this.turnOffElement();
        }
    }

    private turnOffElement(): void {
        var jqElem = $(this.element.nativeElement);

        jqElem.off();
        jqElem.find('*').off();

        // app-opac-50-disabled-cursor-not-authorized is a css class that sets cursor, transparency etc...
        jqElem
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            .attr('href', '')
            .addClass('app-opac-50-disabled-cursor-not-authorized')
            .attr('title', 'Not authorized');

        jqElem
            .find('button')
            .addClass('text-muted')
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        jqElem.find('a')
            .attr('href', '')
            .addClass('app-opac-50-disabled-cursor-not-authorized');

        jqElem.on('click', (e: Event) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage**;

```
<button appEditEntityActions [requiresAnyRole]='["Viewer", "Editor"]' (click)="doSomething();">Sample button</button>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: was using jquery the only way you got this to work?

Comment: @JeremyLove - never tried without JQuery. This article suggests some ways to do it with "pure" angular code; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261962/how-to-set-attributes-on-an-element-in-angular-2/42262022